# The name of a particular low extinction region

Tags: dust, extinction

There is a region called [Baade's window](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baade%27s_Window).

I remember there is a similar region called "somebody's window", which also has a low amount of dust.

Does anyone know the name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Lockman hole?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockman_Hole

It has a column density of neutral hydrogen of $6\times10^{19}$ cm$^{-2}$, which will correspond to very little dust.

Two others I've heard of towards the Galactic bulge are known as the Sgr I and Sgr II windows.

Finally, I offer "Stanek's window" towards the bulge, which has been referred to in a number of the Chandra Galactic plane X-ray surveys but appears to have no refereed publication associated with its discovery. I found this on arXiv.  http://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/9802307  It is at $l=0.25$, $b=-2.15$ and has $E(B-V) \sim 0.6$.

Comment: good, this is the one I want to find.

Answer (score 2):

Puppis Window?
([Neutral hydrogen observations towards the Puppis Window of the Milky Way](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1982A%26AS...50..377S))

Answer (score 1):

I think you are talking about **Plaut's window**, which is located at `l=0°` and `b=-8°`. It has a reddening of `E(B-V)=0.25` magnitudes.

HTH,

Germán.

Comment: not this one. There are other astronomical items called XX window?

Comment: You said with low amount of dust, which means low extinction for me...

Comment: my bad. There should be a more famous window.